# How to find all values which only appear less than X times in a vector

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

I have a vector, in this case a character vector. I want all the elements which only appear once in the vector, but the solution should be generalizable for limits other than 1.

I can pick them manually if I use the `table` function. I thought that the solution would look something like

```
frequencies <- table(myVector)
myVector[??@frequencies <= 1]
```

But first of all, I don't know the slot name which will have to go into ??, and searches for documentation on the `table` object lead me to nowhere.

Second, while [the documentation for table()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/table.html) says that it returns 'an object of class "table"', trying the above with some random word used instead of ??, I didn't get a "no such slot" error, but

> Error: trying to get slot "frequencies" from an object of a basic class ("function") with no slots

which seems to indicate that the above won't function even if I knew the slot name.

So what is the correct solution, and how do I get at the separate columns in a `table` when I need them?

Comment: Your solution doesn’t work because the return value of `table` *has no slots*. Slots only exist in S4 objects and not many (as far as I know, none) of the R built-in functions work with S4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need `table` for this:

```
vector <- c(1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4)
threshold <- 1
```

```
Filter(function (elem) length(which(vector == elem)) <= threshold, vector)
# [1] 0 3 4
```

You *can* use `table`, but then you get the result as character strings rather than numbers. You can convert them back, of course, but it’s somehow less elegant:

```
tab <- table(vector)
names(tab)[tab <= threshold]
# [1] "0" "3" "4"
```

Comment: I found a simple solution myself too, but thank you for providing this one and for mentioning the part about S4 objects and built-in functions.

Answer (score 4):

D'oh, the documentation of the table function led me on a merry chase of imaginary object slots.

Whatever the table() function returns, it acts as a simple numeric vector. So my solution idea works when written as:

```
threshold <- 1
frequencies <- table(myVector)
frequencies[frequencies <= threshold]
```